# pymssql callproc unicode - returns an error

Tags: python, sql-server, unicode, pymssql

I need help on calling "sp_executesql" via callproc (i need it as RPC). this is my code:

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(host='11.22.33.44:1433', user='sa', password='XYZ', database='AdventureWorks')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.callproc("sp_executesql", 'SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Employee WHERE BusinessEntityID = 109')
```

I get this error:

```
  File "executesql.py", line 4, in <module>
    cur.callproc("sp_executesql", 'SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Employee WHERE BusinessEntityID = 109')
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 357, in pymssql.Cursor.callproc (pymssql.c:4238)
    self._returnvalue = proc.execute()
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1289, in _mssql.MSSQLStoredProcedure.execute (_mssql.c:12177)
    check_cancel_and_raise(rtc, self.conn)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1322, in _mssql.check_cancel_and_raise (_mssql.c:12473)
    return maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException(conn)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1366, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException (_mssql.c:13067)
    raise ex
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (214, "Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.DB-Lib error message 214, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Running other stored procedures goes smoothly.
Running the string as unicode (u'Select...') gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "executesql.py", line 4, in <module>
    cur.callproc("sp_executesql", u'SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Employee WHERE BusinessEntityID = 109')
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 354, in pymssql.Cursor.callproc (pymssql.c:4177)
    raise NotSupportedError('Unable to determine database type')
pymssql.NotSupportedError: Unable to determine database type
```

Do you know how to overcome this?

SQL Server is 
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)   Feb 10 2012 19:39:15   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem.  It seems to have been reported in [Issue 56](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/issues/detail?id=56).
So far unresolved. :(

Update: I found a solution to the "None" problem.  See my thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938301/passing-nulls-to-stored-procedure-in-python/12939960#12939960).

Comment: Thanks, @Mike. I saw this "issue 56" you were citing, but I couldn't find the sources that its reported has changed. Do you know where they are? I don't mind building the whole thing from scratch after fixing the bug.

Comment: Go to the Downloads section and download/extract the version for your system.  They're referring to the pymssql.pyx file, which is in the root.  I don't think they changed the project version, maybe just their local copy.  I'm considering attempting a fix too.  If you fix it, though, see Randy's post at the Google group for instructions on making it part of the project.  Link here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/pymssql/lACWoHmAcvI

Comment: @roi, Were you able to compile?  When I compile the resulting files don't work.