# Passing nulls to stored procedure in Python

Tags: python, pymssql

I'm using Python to call a stored procedure in my MSSQL database, but it doesn't like the "None" value passed.  Is this perhaps a bug in pymssql?  Or is there some way to ensure that "None" is converted to NULL?  I need to be able to pass NULL.

example code:

```
cn = pymssql.connect(my connection info)
cur = cn.cursor()
params = range(2)
params[0] = 1
params[1] = None # this needs to pass as NULL
cur.callproc('mystoredproc', params)
```

Comment: a search on google brought up this http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/limitations.php (already from the page name it should ring a bell) and as they suggest here, give a default value to the NULL field and do a check on that to avoid it... im no expert btw, that's why i'm commenting :)

Comment: I need to be able to pass a NULL value to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a known [issue](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/issues/detail?id=56).

Update: I found a solution.  While the pymssql module does need to be fixed, I can use the _mssql module that comes with it and call the lower level routines.

Example:

```
import _mssql
conn = _mssql.connect(connection info, syntax is slightly different than pymssql)
proc = conn.init_procedure('mystoredproc')
proc.bind(1, _mssql.SQLINT4, name='@firstparam')
proc.bind(None, _mssql.SQLINT4, name='@secondparam', null=True)
proc.execute()
```

The "null=True" setting is required to allow this parameter to accept nulls, and the "None" will get converted to a NULL.